# Solitaire in MVC. How to create object based on non monobehavior class?

Tags: unity-game-engine, model-view-controller

I have to make solitaire game. I already made one but now I have to separate the logic from view to make it better to bot for example. It makes me confiused. I wanted to make card class non monobehaviored, then create a deck list with all cards and then create these cards in scene view but I have no idea how to create objects based on the datas from that class. Do ypu have some ideas how to do that? Or maybe you get another idea how to to this? Any tips?

Comment: well `public class Card { ... }` is now an object type that is not a `MonoBehaviour` ... however for visualization at some point you anyway will need one ... so why not just stick to the `MonoBehaviour`? Otherwise you will probably want something like `public class CardVisuals : MonoBehaviour { public void Initialize(Card card){ /*Do whatever is needed to visualize the given card*/ } }`

Comment: Look at StrangeIOC